# Python, How to move mail from junk to inbox in Outlook/Hotmail

Tags: python, email, outlook, hotmail, imaplib

I need to know how to move mail from the junk to inbox folder in Outlook using Python. I know that there is the imaplib and am wondering how to utilize imaplib to do this task.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/imaplib.html) for that module?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6851). After reading the imaplib documentation, using the `UID MOVE` command should be easy.